# How to search a bigint column value in ibdata1?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to find some data, which is in bigint format, in ibdata1 or ib_logfile*.

How can I grep it?

Comment: Why don't you simply recover the table?

Comment: @N.B. I need to find out insert dates of some data.

Comment: You really didn't understand the point of my question, right?

Comment: @N.B. I wasn't clear enough. I don't need to recover the table since it already exists! I need to find the order of insertion for some rows. If you've another/better suggestion other than the given answer please don't hesitate to add it as an answer.

Comment: Not sure the "order of insertion" is going to be discoverable this way... InnoDB stores data in primary key order, splitting pages as needed if rows are not inserted in primary key order or subsequently become larger, and in either case, earlier in the file != evidence earlier insertion.  Your binlogs are a much better place to learn this.  If you aren't backing them up and archiving them, you should consider that.

Comment: Don't search the disk, search the table with sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bgrep](https://bgrep.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) would be a tool for that.

Take into account InnoDB stores integer in non-conventional way. The highest bit flags a sign if type is `SIGNED`. 1 is set if the value is positive.

For example, if a field is declared as `BIGINT` (signed by default) and its value is 38 in the InnoDB table space it will be stored as `0x8000000000000026`.

If the field is declared as `BIGINT UNSIGNED` the 38 value will be stored as `0x0000000000000026`.

Comment: Are you sure?  Every encoding of 'signed' I have heard of stores '+' as '0'.

Comment: Yes I am sure. It's unusual way. hat's why I added the note. But that's not the only case.  In <5.6 DATETIME's highest bit is set as well

Comment: In think pre-5.6 `DATETIME` used "packed decimal".

Comment: It did. *and* the highest bit is set

Comment: Strange.  `2015...` would have a binary `2` in the first 4 bits:  `0010`.

Comment: It's becoming off topic. But feel free to ask it as a separate question.